# Docker: how to containerize a console application that take input from terminal

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I'm playing with the popular Docker tech and just start from scratch. To start up, I would like to first containerize console apps then gradually move to more complex apps, such as web app, etc.

I have successfully containerized a "hello world" app, which will display a sentence on the terminal. However, I hit a wall when I tried to slightly upgrade the app so that it can take input from the terminal.

There are 2 files in the folder, one is the app.py file and the other one is the Dockerfile.

The app.py has the following content:(just 2 lines)

```
name = input("What is your name? ")
print ('hello ' + name + ' from a container!')
```

And the Dockerfile looks like this:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

So both of them are very simple. Then I go to the terminal, navigate to the folder, and build a container by:

```
docker build --tag=helloworld .
```

The build was successful. But once I tried to run it with:

```
docker run helloworld
```

I got the following error message:

```
What is your name? Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 3, in <module>
name = input("What is your name? ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Add the arguments `-ti` to your `docker run`.

Comment: @Klaus D. what is the -ti option? I refer to this doc https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-working-directory--w but cannot find the explaination for this option

Comment: Using short one letter arguments, `-ti` equals `-it` and `-i -t`.

Comment: @Klaus D. OK. So -i can help keep STDIN open. But what can -t do? The link mentioned it could Allocate a pseudo-TTY, but what does a pseudo-TTY even mean in this context?